# How can I return my database values ​through Vertx?

Tags: java, vert.x

Good afternoon, I'm trying to get the values from my database and add them to a list and I always get null. What is the cause and how could it save those values? When it comes to printing by console I have no problem. Best regards.

```
 public List<JsonObject> getAll() {
List<JsonObject> listObject = new ArrayList<JsonObject>();
try {
  this.connect();
  this.client.query("SELECT * FROM user")
    .execute().onSuccess(ar -> {
        for (Row row : ar) {
          listObject.add(row.toJson());
          System.out.println("---- OK " + listObject.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
      }
    );
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
System.out.println("--- Null: " + listObject.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
return listObject;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't use `return` since this is an asynchronous call.

Instead, pass a `Consumer`

```
public void getAll(Consumer<ArrayList<JsonObject>> callback) {

    try {
      this.connect();
      this.client.query("SELECT * FROM user").execute().onSuccess(ar -> {
        List<JsonObject> listObject = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Row row : ar) {
          listObject.add(row.toJson());
        }
        System.out.printf("Fetched %d objects%n", listObject.size());
        callback.accept(listObject);  // this replaces your return statement
      });
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());  // TODO: replace with a proper logger
    }
}
```

Elsewhere, pass in an instance of a consumer

```
databaseClient.getAll(list -> {
  // TODO: use the list to perform some action 
})
```

Otherwise, you might want to look at [R2DBC](https://r2dbc.io/) and how it can be used to wire subscribers to the result-set.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry to ask, but if I wanted it to return the value, how would I have to do it? If possible in any case. Greetings.

Comment: It is not possible to call `return` or modify an external non-final variable that you could return inside of `onSuccess`, no. By default, Vertx should remain non-blocking (which return statements generally exist for blocking methods)